# Collect redis metrics from a specific day

Tags: redis

I want to verify if there were any redis `SET` calls made on a specific day,

The info commandstats give me metrics but im not sure what is the time duration of these metrics.
Like whats the start time and end time these metrics were collected in.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info commandstats
# Commandstats
cmdstat_command:calls=15,usec=5154,usec_per_call=343.60
cmdstat_randomkey:calls=28,usec=515,usec_per_call=18.39
cmdstat_config:calls=584575,usec=30325793,usec_per_call=51.88
cmdstat_mset:calls=14372,usec=134336973,usec_per_call=9347.13
cmdstat_slowlog:calls=1169146,usec=4763189,usec_per_call=4.07
cmdstat_bgsave:calls=1,usec=46854,usec_per_call=46854.00
cmdstat_scan:calls=4,usec=26,usec_per_call=6.50
cmdstat_get:calls=8224808736,usec=7259627651,usec_per_call=0.88
cmdstat_latency:calls=584573,usec=629736,usec_per_call=1.08
cmdstat_dbsize:calls=1,usec=1,usec_per_call=1.00
cmdstat_set:calls=90774923,usec=174928586,usec_per_call=1.93
cmdstat_monitor:calls=2,usec=0,usec_per_call=0.00
cmdstat_info:calls=584577,usec=29221468,usec_per_call=49.99
cmdstat_mget:calls=13448,usec=59812180,usec_per_call=4447.66
cmdstat_ttl:calls=1,usec=1,usec_per_call=1.00
```

I want to see how many `SET` calls were made on September 14th 2021.

Is it possible to get this metric?

Redis version :

```
~$ redis-server -v
Redis server v=4.0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not get this metric by redis self. you need other tools.

1. get `info commandstats` metrics with a timer. eg.. every 20 seconds.
2. diff the delta of two metrics in different time. `2021.9.14` metrics can be calculated by `2021.9.14 00:00:00` and `2021.9.15 00:00:00`